# Flutter Video Player Issue : Preloading Features

Tags: flutter, video-player, preloading, flutter-devtools

I wanted to share a challenge I've encountered while working with the video preloading functionality in Flutter, using the video player dependency.

I've been trying to implement a smooth video preloading mechanism in my Flutter app. My approach involves initializing the first video and playing it, and then asynchronously initializing the second video in the background. However, I've noticed that even with this approach, there's still a noticeable delay during the initialization process.

To make things more complex, I've also attempted to cache these videos to improve loading times. Strangely, when I attempt to load and cache multiple videos together, the app tends to crash or experience significant lag.

Just to give you some insight into my tech stack, I've explored various solutions like cheiwe, better player, and preload_page_view to help with the preloading process. My code structure involves using a PageView.builder and integrating Firebase for video connectivity.

I'm reaching out to to see if anyone has insights into optimizing video preloading, caching, and overall performance. If you've come across any helpful resources, design patterns, or tips, I'd greatly appreciate your input.

Comment: Welcome, please read [ask]. At the moment it is unclear what you're asking. Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service and not a resource recommendation site. Please clarify your question to be about one specific problem, including what you've tried and any errors you've run into.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.